# how to get a specific field value from an object retrieved and bind it to a property in the component TypeScript

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

Hello i have a type script code that populate options from a back end service ,Now how to perform 2 way data binding on  or  
,And how to get a specific field value from the object retrieved 
for Example the Objects i retrieved each one of them is in json format like this :

```
countryCode:"TUR" 
   countryId:185 
   countryName:"Turkey"
   countryPhoneCode:"90"
   __proto__:Object
```

my html is like this :------

```
<div class="form-group ">
                <label class="control-label" for="countryCode">Country</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="countryCode"formControlName="countryCode">
                    <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" 
       [attr.value]="country.countryCode" [selected]="country.countryCode  === viewCountryCode">
                        {{country.countryName}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

here is some of my type script:---

```
    registrationForm: FormGroup;
    username: AbstractControl;
     useremail: AbstractControl;
     commercialWebSiteLink: AbstractControl;
     corporateWebSiteLink: AbstractControl;
  countryCode: String = "jo";
  viewCountryCode: string = "jo";

createSignupForm() {
    this.registrationForm = this.builder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        UserNameValidator.userNameRange,
        UserNameValidator.OnlyAlphabets
      ])],
      useremail: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        EmailValidator.mailFormat,
        EmailValidator.domainCheckFormat,
        EmailValidator.mailLength,
        EmailValidator.specialCharacters
      ])],
      countryCode: [''],
      commercialWebSiteLink: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        UrlValidator.urlFormat,
      ])],

      corporateWebSiteLink: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        UrlValidator.urlFormat,
      ])],
      merchantType: ['PSP']

    });
    this.username = this.registrationForm.controls['username'];
    this.useremail = this.registrationForm.controls['useremail'];
    this.commercialWebSiteLink = this.registrationForm.controls['commercialWebSiteLink'];
    this.corporateWebSiteLink = this.registrationForm.controls['corporateWebSiteLink'];
    this.regestrationErrorMessage = " ";

  }

submitsignup(RegistrationForm: any) {

    if (!RegistrationForm.errors && RegistrationForm.valid) {
      if ((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("termsandConditons")).checked) {
        this.isAcceptTerms = false;
      } else {
        this.isAcceptTerms = true;
      }
      this.homeService.signUpMarchent(RegistrationForm).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.success) {
            this.signUpDone == true;
          } else {
            this.regestrationErrorMessage = this.translate.instant('MerchantRegistration.' + response.code);
            if (this.regestrationErrorMessage == '') {
              this.regestrationErrorMessage = this.translate.instant('MerchantRegistration.errGeneralError');
            }
          }
        },
        error => {
          this.regestrationErrorMessage = this.translate.instant('MerchantRegistration.errGeneralError');
        }


      );
    }
  }
```

Now i want in my type script to retrieve **Country Id** from the object i retrieved , And I want to save it in a type script variable when i submit the form ,so i can then submit it to the back end instead of country code
Any Help will please ,

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved it

```
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="control-label" for="countryId">Country</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="countryId" formControlName="countryId">
                <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" [attr.value]="country.countryId" [selected]="country.countryCode === viewCountryCode">
                    {{country.countryName}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

I made a new form control named in the type script class ,countryId: 1 in the createSignupForm().